# Creating custom Swing Menu Class

Tags: java, swing

I want to create a class that creates a custom JMenu, sets a few parameters and highlights the menu when the user hovers over it. This is what it would look like when done manually:

```
menuBar = new JMenuBar();
menuBar.setOpaque(false);

private Font bold_large = new Font("Helvetica", Font.BOLD, 26);

private Color bgColor = Color.BLACK;
private Color highlighted = Color.GREEN;

    //HERE
    JMenu menu = new JMenu(str);
    menu.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100, 40));
    menu.addMouseListener(new java.awt.event.MouseAdapter() {
        public void mouseEntered(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
            menu.setBackground(highlighted);
        }
        public void mouseExited(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
            menu.setBackground(bgColor);
        }
    });
    menu.setOpaque(true);
    menu.setFont(bold_large);

menuBar.add(menu);
```

I have tried writing a simple constructor in a new class that would create a button like this, with pretty much exactly the same code, but that did not have any effect (i.e. the button did not show up at all). I have also tried overriding the paintComponent, although with little success, as I am still relatively new to Java.

How would I, in general, go about creating such a class? Is overriding the paintComponent the only solution to this? If so, I would much appreciate an example on how to do so properly.

EDIT: This is the class I created, which has no apparent effect:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class HighlightMenu extends JMenu {

private Font bold_large = new Font("Helvetica", Font.BOLD, 26);

private Color bgColor = Color.getHSBColor(0f, 0f, 60/360f);
private Color highlighted = Color.getHSBColor(0f, 0f, 110/360f);

HighlightMenu(String str) {
    JMenu menu = new JMenu(str);
    menu.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100, 40));
    menu.addMouseListener(new java.awt.event.MouseAdapter() {
        public void mouseEntered(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
            menu.setBackground(Color.GREEN);
        }
        public void mouseExited(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
            menu.setBackground(UIManager.getColor("control"));
        }
    });
    menu.setOpaque(true);
    menu.setFont(bold_large);
}
}
```

and my intended Implementation in the main function would look like this:

```
menu = new HighlightMenu("File");
menu.setMnemonic(KeyEvent.VK_D);
menuBar.add(menu);
```

Comment: Does menuBar show up somewhere when you run this?

Comment: Yes, the menuBar shows up and all buttons I manually create like this show up. However, once I put them into an extra class they vanish.

Comment: Overriding paintComponent should not be necessary. But perhaps you could add the code that doesn't seem to work, right now there's no way of telling what's wrong.

Comment: Okay, I edited my post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're creating a JMenu variable inside your HighlightMenu class while extending JMenu. Extending means that it inherits all methods available to JMenu. So there are two solutions, the first one is to add a method that would return this JMenu variable. In this case you wouldn't have to extend JMenu anymore. However, personally I think the solution below is a little better.

I removed the JMenu variable and called the JMenu methods from your class itself. These are accessible because you use `extends JMenu` as explained above.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class HighlightMenu extends JMenu {

    private Font bold_large = new Font("Helvetica", Font.BOLD, 26);

    private Color bgColor = Color.getHSBColor(0f, 0f, 60/360f);
    private Color highlighted = Color.getHSBColor(0f, 0f, 110/360f);

    HighlightMenu(String str) {
        setText(str);
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100, 40));
        addMouseListener(new java.awt.event.MouseAdapter() {
            public void mouseEntered(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
                setBackground(Color.GREEN);
            }
            public void mouseExited(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
                setBackground(UIManager.getColor("control"));
            }
        });
        setOpaque(true);
        setFont(bold_large);
    }
}
```

EDIT extra explanation of what went wrong:

The reason that your menu showed up empty was simply because you were adding an empty JMenu item to it. All actions performed were only done on the menu variable inside HighlightMenu meaning that the object itself still wasn't altered.